# Order data frame rows according to names in a column

Tags: r

I need to reorder rows in data frame (`DF`), according to corresponding names in column of `DF`.
My `DF` looks like this

```
beta    se       hr    m
0.1     0.01     1     xl.vl.pl
0.2     0.02     2     l.vl.ce
0.3     0.03     3     s.vl.fc
0.4     0.04     4     idl.p
0.1     0.01     1     m.vl.pl
0.2     0.02     2     xs.vl.ce
0.3     0.03     3     l.vl.fc
0.4     0.04     4     idl.p
0.4     0.04     4     xxl.vl.pl
```

and I would like to reorder it according to column `m`, so that it would be

```
0.4     0.04     4     xxl.vl.pl
0.1     0.01     1     xl.vl.pl
0.2     0.02     2     l.vl.ce
0.3     0.03     3     l.vl.fc
0.1     0.01     1     m.vl.pl
0.4     0.04     4     idl.p
0.4     0.04     4     idl.p
0.3     0.03     3     s.vl.fc
0.2     0.02     2     xs.vl.ce
```

I appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: `library(fortunes) ; fortune(14)` or `gsub("[^eghlowy?. ]", "", "zrwxxhsuy ppgmomojgliie?...")`

Comment: The output doesn't seem ordered by the column m

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain what is `fortune(14)`

Comment: @adiana It is ordered, but not alphabetically. I think the values xs, m, l, xl etc. represent clothing sizes.

Comment: @user6108949 it kind of stands for "what have you tried by yourself that didn't work? Have you made any research to try and solve your problem?".

Comment: @user6108949 You should be more clear and specify how you want to order the column, if it's not alphabetically we cannot figure it out by ourselves

Comment: @adiana, i would like to order rows in descending order -> `xxl, xl, l, m, idl ,s, xs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
orderLevels<-c("xxl","xl","l","m","idl","s","xs")

library(dplyr)
DF<-DF %>% mutate(m2 = match(sapply(strsplit(DF$m, "[.]"), function(x) x[1]), orderLevels)) %>% arrange(m2) %>% select(-m2)
```

Comment: you can use `match` to get the order : `DF[order(match(sub("([^.]+)\\..+", "\\1", DF$m), orderLevels)), ]` will work, or `DF[order(match(sapply(strsplit(DF$m,"[.]"), function(x) x[1]), orderLevels)), ]` to keep your `strsplit` statement

Comment: Yes yours is definitely more concise :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use an ordered factor corresponding to the first part of m (that you can retrieve with a call to `sub`), ordered according to your will (`xxl, xl, l, m, idl ,s, xs`) and then you can order your data.frame using it:

```
DF[order(factor(sub("([^.]+)\\..+", "\\1", DF$m), 
   levels=c("xxl", "xl", "l", "m", "idl" ,"s", "xs"), ordered=TRUE)), ]

 # beta   se hr         m
# 9  0.4 0.04  4 xxl.vl.pl
# 1  0.1 0.01  1  xl.vl.pl
# 2  0.2 0.02  2   l.vl.ce
# 7  0.3 0.03  3   l.vl.fc
# 5  0.1 0.01  1   m.vl.pl
# 4  0.4 0.04  4     idl.p
# 8  0.4 0.04  4     idl.p
# 3  0.3 0.03  3   s.vl.fc
# 6  0.2 0.02  2  xs.vl.ce
```